# Why does my metric show twice in grafana UI?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm using a simple github stars exporter. Sometimes my metrics "duplicate" (see the image below) and i don't know why. It's not really a duplication, it's an old data item that gets included into the query result, but i've no idea why. It's not the first time i get this using prometheus+grafana so maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Query: github_repo_stars > 1

Relative time: 14d

Legend: {{repo}}

Type: Range

Graph: Time series

[image]

Comment: Each entry is a unique series, meaning a unique combination of labels. Your legend is using just the repo label, which is common between those two series. If you looked at the other labels (maybe try verbose legend while debugging), there will be some label/s which are unique between them.

Comment: @Brad Why doesn't it group labels together ? I'm don't understand that.

Comment: I see the time series are deemed different because for this particular repo, a "Language=Python" property was added days ago. However I don't care about this and would want the two time series to merge and only keep most recent values. In my case the 1st time series ends when the 2nd time series starts so there is no "overlapping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we determined in the comments, you have two unique series that are being displayed in your legend. Whether or not you have multiple is determined by a couple of things in this case:

- The time range you are querying, and whether or not the additional series exist in this range.
- The unique combination of labels for each series. In this case, you have an additional label `Language=Python` that was added, causing the previous series to end and the new series to start.

---

**Solution**

You need to introduce an [aggregation operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) to your PromQL in order to combine these multiple series.

In this case, where you have one series end and another start, it doesn't matter as much which operator you implement, and any of sum/min/max/avg should give the same result. I'll use max below to explain the **by** and **without** clause.

```
# Remove all labels except for repo
max by (repo) (github_repo_stars > 1)

# or remove only the Language label and keep the others
max without (Language) (github_repo_stars > 1)
```

> without removes the listed labels from the result vector, while all other labels are preserved in the output. by does the opposite and drops labels that are not listed in the by clause, even if their label values are identical between all elements of the vector.